# How to set http-only true in cookies --?? in angular js

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am already set true value of "secure" in cookies like this its working fine--

```
$cookies.putObject('keyname', $scope.keyname,{secure:true});
```

but when i set value of "http-only" in cookies its not working-

```
$cookies.putObject('keyname', $scope.keyname,{httpOnly:true});
```

How can i set value of http-only in cookies?

Thanks in advance